# Replace keys JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a JSON object like

```
var myjson = {
   "com.mycompany.top.Element" : {
      "com.mycompany.top.count" : 10,
      "com.mycompany.top.size" : 0
      ....
   }
};
```

And I want to replace the dots/periods in the keys with a colon so the JSON becomes:

```
var myjson = {
   "com:mycompany:top:Element" : {
      "com:mycompany:top:count" : 10,
      "com:mycompany:top:size" : 0
      ....
   }
};
```

The JSON2 from Doublos Crockford just replaces the values not keys.  Wondered if anybody else hade written a regexp or parser to replace the text making up the key?

Comment: Are you dealing with JSON, or an actual JavaScript object? They are different things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this recursive function:

```
function rewriteProperties(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") return obj;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            obj[prop.replace(/\./g, ":")] = rewriteProperties(obj[prop]);
            if (prop.indexOf(".") > -1) {
                delete obj[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```