# Slice() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Hmmm, I have checked everywhere but still haven't been able to cut it... from my Google maps site which works but my efforts to "slice" the variable "point" do not.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
```

**Example:**
     +point+ (print out the result)

This prints out **(28.7035649, -105.9697253)** which is correct.

---

So, I want to strip off the parenthesis using slice()

---

**Example:**

```
 point = point.slice(1, -1);

 +point+ (print out the result)
```

This does not work - Uncaught TypeError: point.slice is not a function.

---

**Example:**

```
 var str;
 str =  point;
 str = str.slice(1, -1);
 +str+ (print out the result)
```

This does not work - Uncaught TypeError: str.slice is not a function.

---

**Example:**
This does work:

```
 var str;
 str = "(28.7035649, -105.9697253)";
 str = str.slice(1, -1);
 +str+ (print out the result)
```

This prints out **28.7035649, -105.9697253** which is correct - no parenthesis.

Any clues to what is happening here?

Comment: I´d say that Objects doenst support slice function since slice is for strings

Comment: `slice()` is a method of javascript `string` or `array`, but u have `google.maps.LatLng` object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My question "Slice() not working as expected" has kind of been answered and other points regarding Google Maps will require a new question.

So as to be clear the answer by madox2 while correct syntax, does not work with Google Maps "**point**":

**point.toString().slice(1, -1);**
Print out **point** and the parenthesis are still there!

The following does work:

**var newpoint = point.toString().slice(1, -1);**
Print out **newpoint** and the parenthesis are gone!

I have not received an explanation as to WHY but I thank you all for your answers nonetheless. (Come back PHP - all is forgiven!)

Answer (score 3):

return value in your first example is an `object` and objects don't have `slice` method defined but strings does which is why the last example works.

In the second example you are assigning the same `point` object to `str` variable which does not convert into a string.

Answer (score 0):

LatLng class has `lat()` and `lng()` methods, which you can use to get these values:

```
var lat = point.lat();
var lng = point.lng();
```

See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

Comment: Thank you for the comment and advice Gothdo, and your code does indeed provide the lat, lng however using that in Google street view API does not produce a result ("We have no imagery for this location") **(image) size=100x62&location=lat,lng&heading=heading&pitch=0;** Using the slice() method above does produce a street view location thumbnail but the location is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, slice is method of string and you use it on object. What you can do:

```
point.toString().slice(1, -1);
```

see docs [LatLng class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng).

EDIT:

Notice that `point.toString()` does not change actual `point` variable, it **returns** a string which represents the point, so that you can assign it to new variable e.g. `var pointString = point.toString()`.

The same happens with `pointString.slice(1, -1)` or `point.toString().slice(1, -1)`, you need a variable to hold that data e.g. `var myPoint = point.toString().slice(1, -1)`. You can also reuse the `point` variable like `point = point.toString().slice(1, -1)`, but you loose reference to original point object.

Comment: This gives the Stray Dog a solution but your answer should go into WHY it is the proper solution.

Comment: Almost correct, but true as Enkode says I am "not understanding it yet"... point.toString().slice(1, -1); does not strip off the parenthesis in my environment but var NEWPOINT = point.toString().slice(1, -1); does. I can print out the value correctly 21.1210537, -101.6823321 however (image) size=100x62&location=NEWPOINT&heading=NEWHEADING&pitch=0; does indeed produce a thumbnail but it is an unknown location so I am still baffled unless the result has something to do do with Google's API. (NEWHEADING works also pitch)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to access not existed method for LatLng object. Also **note** that's duplicate question [How do I stringify a google LatLng object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181143/how-do-i-stringify-a-google-latlng-object)

Shortly use solution below to stringify LatLng object ( source: link above) and apply `slice` method to result of function below.

```
function formatData(data) {
    //data is an array of many LatLng objects

    newData = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj['lat'] = data[i].lat();
        obj['lon'] = data[i].lng();
        newData.push(obj);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(newData);     
}
```

Comment: <?php **$lat = "46.414382"; $lng = "10.013988"; $NEWHEADING = "151.78"; $Pitch = "0";** $StreetViewThumb = "(Stack Overflow strips out the actual url) <img src size=150x93&location=$lat,$lng&heading=$NEWHEADING&pitch=$Pitch' alt='CompanyName'>"; echo $StreetViewThumb; ?> THIS WORKS in php and displays the correct street view thumb - but not in javascript which is what I am trying to achieve here. I guess I could embed php in my javascript but that strikes me as bad practice and unneccessary.

Comment: Thank you Andriy but I am not trying to "stringify", I am simply trying to remove the parenthesis from the "**point**" variable - while that might involve  converting the variable to a string temporarily to perform the operation is true, but your code example (with respect) is irrelevant.

Comment: @Stray thanks for your comments, would update code when i have a minute