# Google maps API v3 stopped returning latitude or longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a rails app where users can plot locations on a map, on save the latlng is saved in a hidden field using javascript and gmap3.js.

The map and the markers are showing but the latlng is being saved as nil.

The code has not been changed recently but I noticed the console is now saying that maps v=3.9 is now retired. I tried changing it to v=3 but that didn't help.

I don't understand this js but it seems to work fine other than the latitude and longitude returning undefined. Should I rebuild the feature from scratch or focus on the API?

Application.html.haml:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9'
```

plotLocations.js:

```
$.fn.plotLocations = function(){

  var $form       = this;
  if ($form.length === 0) { return false; }
  var centre = $form.find('#locations').data('centre');
  var locations = {};

  function updateLocations(id, latLng) {
    locations[id] = latLng;
  }

  function removeLocation(id) {
    delete locations[id];
  }

  function setupInfoBoxForCross(marker){
    $('.infoBox').remove();

    $map = $('#locations');

    var html = '<div>'                                          +
                '<a href="javascript:;" id="marker_'            +
                    marker.__gm_id                              +
                  '">'                                          +
                  '<img src="/assets/map_icon_remove.png">'                                            +
                '</a>'                                          +
              '</div>'                                          ;

    var myOptions = {
      content: html,
      disableAutoPan: false,
      maxWidth: "15px",
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -60),
      zIndex: null,
      boxStyle: {
        background: "white",
        opacity: 0.75,
        width: "09px",
        height: "15px"
       },
      closeBoxURL: "",
      infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
      isHidden: false,
      pane: "floatPane",
      enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    ib.open(marker.map, marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(ib,'domready',function(){
      $('.infoBox a#marker_' + marker.__gm_id).click(function(e){
        marker.setMap(null);
        removeLocation(marker.__gm_id);
        ib.close();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    });

  }


  $("#locations").gmap3({
    marker:{
      values: _.map($('#locations').data('locations'),function(item){return {'latLng': item};}),
      options:{
        draggable: true,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/marker.png')
      },
      events: {
                dragend: function(marker, event){
                  updateLocations(marker.__gm_id, event.latLng);
                },
                mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
                  setupInfoBoxForCross(marker, event, context);
                },
                mouseout: function(marker, event, context){

                }
      },
      callback: function(markers){
    _.each(markers, function(marker){
      updateLocations(marker.__gm_id, marker.position);
    });
  }
},
map: {
  options: {
    center:             centre,
    zoom:               13,
    mapTypeControl:     false,
    zoomControl:        true,
    scrollwheel:        true,
    streetViewControl:  false
  },
  events: {
    click: function(map, event) {
      this.gmap3({
        marker: {
          latLng: event.latLng,
          options: {
            draggable: true,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/marker.png')
          },
          events: {
            dragend: function(marker, event){
              updateLocations(marker.__gm_id, event.latLng);
            },
            mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
              setupInfoBoxForCross(marker, event, context);
            }
          },
          callback: function(marker){
            updateLocations(marker.__gm_id, event.latLng);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
  });
  $form.submit(function(e){
    if ( _.keys(locations).length > 0 ){
      var list = _.map(_.values(locations), function(item){ return _.values(item); });
      $form.find('#project_locations').val(JSON.stringify(list));
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: What is `marker.__gm_id`?

Comment: API version v3.9 was retired a really long time ago.  Most recently [v3.20 was retired, v3.21 became frozen, v3.22 became release and v3.23 became active as the "experimental" version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).  You will probably need to write code to specifically get the latitude and longitude from the google.maps.LatLng objects.

Comment: related question: [How do I stringify a google LatLng object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181143/how-do-i-stringify-a-google-latlng-object)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I think that is the unique ID for each marker. 

After using alert(latLng) I've discovered it is getting the data but the marker.__gm_id is returning "undefined" so I think the problem may be due to the marker id's not being saved.

Comment: There is no documented unique ID for a `google.maps.Marker`. There may have been a undocumented property `__gm_id`  , but you can't rely on undocumented features. You'll need to implement a unique marker-ID on your own.

Comment: Thanks, Ive sorted the IDs now but it seems that wasnt the issue either. I think the issue has to be how the array of locations is passed in to the JSON stringify. So close now :)

`var list = _.map(_.values(locations), function(item){ return _.values(item);` });